# Api transfering another Api response

Tags: java, xml, spring, api, unmarshalling

My team and I are working on some old but quite big application using GWT 2.4 (JDK 1.6.0_45).

We am currently facing a [public API](https://api.isan.org/swagger-ui.html) using HTTP protocol. They recently switch to HTTPS which is not well consumed by Java 6 (free version).

I had multiple solution :

- Upgrade to a maintenable, but not free, Java 6 version (We would like to avoid paying)
- Upgrade to Java 8 (GWT 2.4 which is not compatible with Java 8, so we also have to upgrade to GWT 2.8 and this will take some time considering the size of the application)
- Developping a small Api catching the response of this public API and sending it back to my application with a HTTP protocol

I started the third solution but I am facing some problems with the unmarshalling of the response (xml) received.

Here is what I did until now:

My API method calling the public API:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<WorkMetadataType> lookupWithFilter(String authorization, String filter, String id, Optional<String> accept, Optional<String> xISANAuthorization, Optional<String> idtype) {
    WorkMetadataType res = isanApi.lookupWithFilter(authorization, filter, id, accept.orElse(null), xISANAuthorization.orElse(null), idtype.orElse(null));
    if (res == null) {
        throw new WorkNotFoundException();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(res);
}
```

The method calling the public API.

```
public WorkMetadataType lookupWithFilter(String authorization, String filter, String id, String accept, String xISANAuthorization, String idtype) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(getHttpClient()));
    try {
        CustomMarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter;
        converter = new CustomMarshallingHttpMessageConverter(JAXBContext.newInstance(ISANDataType.class));
        converter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        logger.error("Erreur lors de la définition du marshaller", e);
    }
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, getHeaders(authorization, accept, xISANAuthorization));

    return restTemplate.exchange(getRequestUri(id, idtype, filter), HttpMethod.GET, entity, WorkMetadataType.class).getBody();
}
```

As you can see, I am using Spring and his RestTemplate class. Problem is, you need to specify response's nature which I would like to avoid because of my unmarshalling issues.

My question is : is it possible to transfer the response of this public API to my Application without consuming it while being received by my API ? (simply, doing a copy/paste of it)

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but if you pass authorization or other sensitive data to the api you probably really want to upgrade to https.

Comment: Which Java 6 (free version) is strugling with unfortunatly...

Comment: If you use `Resource` as the target class of the request, this has a `getInputStream()` method (if it `isReadable()`) which you can then use to just straight up transfer the data received (assuming you have a `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` registered on your `RestTemplate`).

Comment: Place something in front of your applicaiton (ngix, apache httpd) which does the SSL/HTTPS stuff and internally uses http.

Comment: @M. Deinum, it could be way quicker indeed. I never worked with them so I will dig a bit in this direction, thx.

Comment: @BeUndeed, I tried your solution, but I got `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly used a HttpCliendBuilder to build my request and get an InputStream as a response.
This way I can just convert it in String and create a ResponseEntity with it.